# Lodash: How to add new field to all values in collection

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Example:

```
var arr = [{name: 'a', age: 23}, {name: 'b', age: 24}]  
var newArr = _.enhance(arr, { married : false });

console.log(newArr); // [{name: 'a', age: 23, married : false}, {name: 'b', age: 24, married : false}]
```

I'm looking for something to do this. Note, **enhance** is not present in lodash.
Is it possible to do this with lodash?
If not -- possible addition?

Thanks,

Comment: Is `newArr` intended to be a whole new array with whole new objects? i.e. should `arr` be left untouched?

Answer (score 56):

<s>You probably want to `extend` `each` of your objects.</s>

mu is too short sort of killed my wordplay while making an excellent point. Updated to create an entirely new array.

```
var arr = [{name: 'a', age: 23}, {name: 'b', age: 24}];

var newArr = _.map(arr, function(element) { 
     return _.extend({}, element, {married: false});
});
```

---

If you want to add it to the library,

```
_.enhance = function(list, source) {
    return _.map(list, function(element) { return _.extend({}, element, source); });   
}
```

Comment: You're modifying `arr` in-place and lodash's `each` will return `arr` so `newArr` is misleading; you don't need to `_.extend` at all, you can do the same thing with `function(e) { e.married = false }` (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8c7ch/). If you mean to make a copy then you'd want to use `_.map` and `_.extend({}, element, { married: false })`.

Comment: @muistooshort excellent point; updated answer. I kept `extend` because I think it's a better general solution, if you wanted to add multiple fields or already had the extension saved as an object. (I am also very tired, so if I missed something else, feel free to edit.)

Comment: Thanks guys! Its easy to do this with a callback function. But the intention of this question is to check if this could be done without it. If there is no such function, is it worth adding to the lib?

Comment: @user1422950 I don't understand. What do you have against callbacks? How do you think the other methods in lodash work?

Comment: I'm not against callbacks. They are natural. I was just looking for some shorthand version of doing it.

Comment: @user1422950 there is no method which does what you request. I have defined a method which does what you request. The method can be comfortably read as a one-liner. What am I missing?

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks @Mathletics, now the method is called _.assign

Comment: Luis Lasser means that now Lodash's `extend` function is called `assign`.

Comment: A little bit `ES6`'tified version: `const newArr = arr.map(element => assign({}, element, {married: false}))`

Answer (score 16):

I use ES6 syntax. I think this will help to u.

```
var arr = [{name: 'a', age: 23}, {name: 'b', age: 24}];    
arr.map((element) => {
   return element.married = false;
});
console.log(arr); // [{name: 'a', age: 23, married : false}, {name: 'b', age: 24, married : false}]
```

Comment: The purpose of `arr.map()` is to return a new array. Here you aren't returning a new array, you're mutating `arr` ... so why not use arr.forEach() instead? 
`
arr.forEach((element) => {
   element.married = false
})
`

Answer (score 16):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com) and ES6 arrow notation the solution can become quite short:

```
const newArr = _.map(arr, o => _.extend({married: false}, o));
```

Note: I use the object `{married: false}` as the first argument since mutating this object leaves the original array intact. This means however that `married` becomes the first field in the resulting object, but this is probably not relevant.

Answer (score 7):

ES6 with [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
const arr = [{name: 'a', age: 23}, {name: 'b', age: 24}, {name: 'c', age: 25}];
const newArr = arr.map(el => ({ ...el, married: false }));

console.log(newArr);  
// [{age: 23, married: false, name: 'a'}, {age: 24, married: false, name: 'b'}, {name: 'c', age: 25, married: false}]
```

Note: Arrow functions returing an object literal need to wrap the object with parenthesis, e.g., `() => ({})`

Answer (score 1):

The function lodash has that is closest to what you want is merge: http://lodash.com/docs#merge

The only slight difference between how merge works and what you want to do is you would need to have an array of equal length to arr all that looks like:

```
var arr = [{name: 'a', age: 23}, {name: 'b', age: 24}];
var marriedArr = [{married : false}, {married : false}];
var newArr = _.merge(arr, marriedArr);
console.log(newArr);
```

If you attempt to do:

```
var newArr = _.merge(arr, {married : false});
```

Then merge will work just like concat.

Answer (score -3):

This comes late and it doesn't involve lodash, but I think the cleanest solution if you want the old data mutable is to use a classic for loop iteration. This way you won't load up the memory with a new array.